# Как правильно написать "прием по обычному графику" или "прием по-обычному графику" и почему?

Tags: раздельно-дефис

Как правильно написать "прием по обычному графику" или "прием по-обычному графику" и почему?

Answer (score 3):

По графику (*какому?*) обычному. *По* - ***предлог***; как и полагается, употреблён с существительным, только отделён от него прилагательным  *обычному*.

Ср.: *выглядеть (как?) по-обычному*. *По - обычному* - наречие с ***приставкой*** *по* и суффиксом *-ому*. Такие наречия пишутся через дефис.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно написать "прием по обычному графику", слово "обычному" - это не наречие, а прилагательное в роли определения.

Но: Всё пошло по-обычному. Было тут по-обычному шумно и суетно. Здесь наречие "по-обычному" с дефисным написанием.

Answer (score -1):

Если  предлог  стоит  перед  словом, а  в  слове  есть  суффикс  ОМу  или  ЕМУ, то  дефис  нужен. 
По-моему,  по-твоему.

Comment: Вопрос был конкретный, не абстрактный. По-моему.

Comment: А Вы умеете отличать приставку от предлога?

Comment: А ещё из детских сказок можно было такое запомнить: "по щучьему велению, по моему хотению...".